# How to take ownership of variable for non-function code-chunk

Tags: rust

```
for tower in &mut game.towers {
    tower.towers_attack(&mut game)
};
```

gives `cannot borrow game as mutable more than once at a time [E0499]`

My code was working however I was refactoring for it to make more sense.

What did work was (main point to note is it is fine with looping twice mutably over the game object, however this is because function has ownership of 'game'?)

```
impl Attack for Game {
    fn towers_attack(&mut self) {
        for tower in &mut self.towers {
            tower.attacked = false;
            if tower.hp.is_positive() {
                for creep in &mut self.lane_creeps {
                    if tower.position.distance_between(creep.position) < 12.0 &&
                       creep.side != tower.side && !tower.attacked {
                        creep.hp -= tower.attack_damage as i32;
                        tower.attacked = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

game.towers_attack();
```

Moving the first loop to outside the function and implementing on `tower` rather than `game.tower` causes the issue.

I've confused myself a lot, I believe I just need to give ownership of `game` to `for tower in &mut game.towers { tower.towers_attack(&mut game) };` then return ownership when it exits, therefore no borrowing occurs if I explicitly give ownership, however I'm not sure if this is possible or makes sense.

The `towers_attack` function is

```
impl TowerAttack for Tower {
    fn towers_attack(&mut self, game: &mut Game) {
        self.attacked = false;
        if self.hp.is_positive() {
            for creep in &mut game.lane_creeps {
                if self.position.distance_between(creep.position) < 12.0 &&
                   creep.side != self.side && !self.attacked {
                    creep.hp -= self.attack_damage as i32;
                    self.attacked = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for tower in &mut game.towers {
    tower.towers_attack(&mut game)
}
```

Rust prevents this call because the implementation of `towers_attack` *might* be:

```
fn towers_attack(game: &mut Game) {
    game.towers.clear()
}
```

or maybe

```
fn towers_attack(game: &mut Game) {
    game.towers.push(...)
}
```

which causes the vector to be reallocated and thus the iterator to be invalidated, which would cause Bad Things To Happen.

Instead, pass the subset of items you need to `towers_attack`. For example:

```
fn towers_attack(lane_creeps: &mut Vec<Creeps>) { ... }
```

> I just need to give ownership of game to `for tower in &mut game.towers { tower.towers_attack(&mut game) };`

You **always** transfer ownership of the expression to the `for` loop. In this case, you are passing *ownership of a mutable reference* to `towers`.

> then return ownership when it exits

There's no way to do that; `for` loops do not return anything.

Comment: thankyou very much! Everything makes a lot more sense now. was confusing myself massively

Comment: @user3920439 no problem! Make sure to upvote questions and answers you find useful here on Stack Overflow, and accept questions that help you the most.